# SQL contact site

Tags: php, sql, database

I want to make a site for personal use that stores my contacts in a database. How would I select all the contacts from the database and echo them out? I have their first name and last name in the database and I want to know how I would get each of their first names and echo them out.

This is where I have gotten so far:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
if($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {

    }
}
```

But I don't know how to select them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The row is just an associative array - index it as usual.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
if($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)) {
        echo $query_row['firstname']; // Or whatever you called the field
    }
}
```

Comment: That will do it for all of the contacts? Say I have five, it will echo out all five of them?

Comment: @TannerEllis: Yup - that's what the `while` loop is for.

Comment: Okay,I've done query_row on other things, but I didn't think it would work for this. Thanks!

Comment: @TannerEllis, indeed it would. The `*` in the SQL query is used to select everything in a specified table.

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts";
$query_run = mysql_query($query);
if($query_run = mysql_query($query)){
    while($query_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query_run)){
      echo query_row["firstname"]." ".query_row["lastname"];    
    }
}
```